# Functional Analysis- Showing Norm equals to infimum of this set

Tags: functional-analysis

If $X$ is a Normed Linear Space, then show that for any $x\in X$ we have $\|x\|=\inf S$, where
$$
S:=\left\{ \frac{1}{|\alpha|}: \alpha \in \mathbb{K}-\{0\} , \|\alpha x\|\leq 1\right\}
$$

I have shown that if $m\in S$ then $\|x\|\leq m$.
But how do I show the greatest upper bound?

Comment: Hint : $||\alpha x|| = |\alpha| \times ||x||$. Use this to rewrite the inequality defining the set $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x \neq 0$. Let $m$ be the infimum. Then for any $\epsilon >0$ there exists $\alpha$ such that $\|\alpha x\| \leq 1$ and $m+\epsilon >\frac 1{|\alpha|}$. Since $|\alpha| \leq \frac 1 {\|x\|}$ we get $m+\epsilon >\|x\|$. Since $\epsilon$ is arbitrary this gives $m \geq \|x\|$. The reverse inequality follows easily by noting that $\|\alpha x \|\leq 1$ when  $\alpha =\frac 1 {\|x\|}$.

The result is obvious when $x=0$.

Comment: Sir $ S:=\left\{ \frac{1}{|\alpha|}: \alpha \in \mathbb{K}-\{0\} , \|\alpha x\|\leq 1\right\}=\left\{ \frac{1}{|\alpha|}: \alpha \in \mathbb{K}-\{0\} , \|x\|\leq \frac{1}{\alpha}\right\} =$ $S:=\left\{ m: m\in \mathbb{K}-\{0\} , \|x\|\leq m\right\} $ Thus $\|x\|=\inf S$ works?

Comment: @SunShine Yes, that works too.